# Operators of order $k$ between Sobolev spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

It may sound like tautology, but I have a problem in proving that differential operator of order $k$ is an operator of order $k$.
What exactly I'm asking for? Let $M$ be a manifold and $E,F$ be two vector bundles over it (here $M$ is not assumed to be compact but in most cases 
it is so): then an order $k$ differential operator is an operator which can be locally expressed as
$D=\sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} A_{\alpha}\frac{\partial^{\alpha}}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1}...\partial x_n^{\alpha_n}}$ and an operator of order $k$ is 
understood as an operator $T:\Gamma_c^{\infty}(M,E) \to \Gamma_c^{\infty}(M,F)$ (acting on smooth, compactly supported sections) which extends 
to *bounded* operator $T:W^{s}(M,E) \to W^{s-k}(M,F)$ where $W^s$ are Sobolev spaces defined as the completion of $\Gamma^{\infty}_c$ with respect to 
certain norm (which is defined precisely in the discussion [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696393/sobolev-spaces-of-sections-of-vector-bundles). 
It is not to hard to verify this in local coordinates but I have a trouble to understand the global picture-in other words I don;t see why the gluing process would not spoil anything (in the noncompact case let us assume
that the matrices $A_{\alpha}$ are *bounded*). If we compute $\|D\xi\|_{s-k,F}$ we get $\sum_i \|k_i \circ (f_i D\xi) \circ \varphi_i^{-1}\|_{s-k,\mathbb{R}^n}$.
If I had not made a mistake the expression $k_i \circ (f_i D\xi) \circ \varphi_i^{-1}$ evaluated on $y=\varphi_i(x)$ is equal to 
$f_i(x)\sum_{|\alpha| \leq k}A_{\alpha}(\varphi_i(x))D^{\alpha}(h_i \circ \xi \circ \varphi_i^{-1})(y)$ (where $h_i$ and $k_i$ are trivialisations (to be precise, we compose it with coordinate charts) for $E$ and $F$ resp. and $f_i$ is the partition of unity). Therefore the norm of $D\xi$ is
$$\|D\xi\|_{s-k},F=\sum_{i}\|(f_i \circ \varphi_i^{-1})(\sum_{|\alpha| \leq k}A_{\alpha}D^{\alpha}(h_i \circ \xi \circ \varphi_i^{-1})\|_{s-k,\mathbb{R}^n}$$
However $\|\xi\|_{s,E}=\sum_{i}\|h_i \circ \xi \circ \varphi_i^{-1}\|_{s,\mathbb{R}^n}$ and I don't see how to get an estimate $\|D\xi\|_{s-k,F} \leq C\|\xi\|_{s,E}$:
**1** First of all, I see the problem where our $M$ need not to be compact: in these case the covering by charts may be infinite and the norms of "local parts" of our differential operators may not be uniformly bounded.
**2** Secondly, even when our manifold $M$ is compact, how do we proceed in order to still have $f_i$'s at the end? It seems to me that if I use the local estimate, then $f_i$ is no longer on the right hand side of my inequality?
I have a problem in veryfing this and in all literature that I know authors state that this is trivial. I tried to be really precise and trace carefully in which space we are working (I mean all *identifications via charts and trivialisations* stuff). Therefore I will be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: don't you consider in a first time $M = \mathbb{R}^n$, and then choose the definitions for the general case in such a way that everything works fine ?

Comment: Yes, for $\mathbb{R}^n$ everything works fine, so the problem with the lack of compactness (in the first question above) arises when our manifold is such that it can not be covered by finite coordinate charts. The second question is exactly about why everything works fine in the general (say-compact) case.